# Making the categories layer style which shows features overlapping another layer in a different color

Tags: qgis, symbology, intersection, intersect

I have tried with this new QGIS function from expression engine but it is not working.

Here is the query I have tried:

```
overlay_touches('Master_3307To3339',filter:= within(geometry(@parent),@map_extent))
```

I don't want it to check all parent layer features every time I create, so make it check only map extend visible parent layer features. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `layer rendering` option to `darken` overlays.

You can play with the various options instead of `darken` to find a suitable output.

[image]